# Handling POST requests with http.server module

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7.4 and http.server module to receive POST requests that contain a file from an ERP.

Everything works fine (file get received and written correctly) except ERP get connection timeout error.

It's first time I use http.server which looks pretty simple but for sure I'm missing something.

See code below, isnt't "self.send_response(200)" enough?

On ERP vendor website they provide an example in PHP to receive data:

```
if (move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "items.xml")){
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

So ERP expect "OK" after successful connection/transfer

Here it is my Python code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time
import cgi

class Test_Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print("POST request received")
        self.send_response(200)
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=self.rfile, headers=self.headers, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'CONTENT_TYPE': self.headers['Content-Type'],})
        f = open("data/test-orig.xml","wb+")
        f.write(form['file'].value)
        f.close()

httpd = HTTPServer((hostName, hostPort), Test_Server)

print(time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (hostName, hostPort))

try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

httpd.server_close()
print(time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (hostName, hostPort))
```

Best regards,

cid

Answer (score 0):

Manage to do it easily with Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/post-data', methods=['POST'])
def test_server():
    data = request.files['file']
    data.save('data/test.xml')
    return "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Solved!